# How can I edit the command-line in LLDB?

Tags: c++, lldb

Is there any way to edit commands easily in lldb? For example gdb has readline support which means I can use vi keybindings to surf across the command line. Is there something similar for lldb?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

lldb uses editline rather than readline for command line editing.  By default, editline comes up in an emacs-like mode, so using the arrow keys or ^a to go the beginning and ^e the end of a line.  ^r searches backward in command history.  If you're on macOS, Option-left & right arrow to go by word, etc...

editline has a vi mode as well (run `man editrc` for details).  I've actually never used it however, so I don't know how well it works.